# using amidst in mathematic

Tags: grammar, adverbs, mathematics, collocation

I use a very formal writing style.

If I want to say that I calculate a function between 5 times between each two points, can I use *amid* these ways?

> The function f(t) is calculated 5 times amidst each given point.
>
> The function f(t) is calculated 5 times amidst each step size.

Here I mean in between each two points or inside each step size(the section between two points).

[image: http://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/image.axd?picture=image_14.png]

Comment: Do you mean "I calculate a function at 5 points located between each two given points"?

Comment: Have you checked the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amidst)?

Comment: I would not advise using "amidst' in any sort of technical writing.  (Especially without checking the definition first.)

Comment: *Amid(st)* is just short for *in the middle of*.

Comment: @zimbra314 yes it is

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes i did

Comment: @Anonym I know but referring to difference between among and amid, i am trying to be cautious  about its usage.

Comment: @HotLicks the dictionary talks about meaning but not collocation in this particular example. How about amid?

Comment: Neither amid nor amidst mean *collocation*.

Comment: Seems like you're intentionally trying to obfuscate your writings. This makes no sense and if you do this to cargo-cult mimic the high academic style, you will only fool those who don't understand your subject matter and could also be fooled by a random math paper generator program. Real experts always strive for clarity and a lot of work goes into simplifying and streamlining the text so that it's minimally distracting. If I read something like "amidst", I would think the writer does not take the topic seriously and is mocking the readers.

Comment: *Amid(st)* and *Between* are not interchangeable.  Looking at the dictionary definitions, I don't understand how people even come up with the idea that they might be.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the function is calculated for five points *between* each two points, or at five points *along the line connecting* each two points.

But we don't know whether the points at which the function is calculated are *evenly distributed* along that line. If so, it would be good to say so.

In any case, "amidst" is much too vague for such a mathematical description.